# Modulus of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

$z_1, z_2$ and $z_3$ are complex numbers related by:

$$z_3=\sqrt{\frac{z_1}{z_2}}$$

When I take the modulus (defined for a complex number)of the L.H.S, how do I reflect that on the R.H.S? Am I allowed to directly take the modulus of the complex numbers on the R.H.S separately and write this:

$$|z_3|=\sqrt{\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}}\ ?$$

Comment: Somebody should mention that $$\sqrt{\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}}$$ exists but $$\sqrt{\frac{z_1}{z_2}}$$ does not. (Unrelated: 1. Please replace each `\cfrac` by `\frac`. 2. There is no "conjugate" in the question, hence why the title?)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : you can use exponential form of a complex number : $z = re^{i\theta}$.

Edit : here is more details.

Write your complex numbers as $z_1 = r_1e^{i\theta_1}, r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ and $r_3e^{i\theta_3}$. 
Notice that $\sqrt z_1 = \sqrt r_1 e^{i\theta_1/2}$, $\sqrt{\frac{z_2}{z_3}} = \sqrt{\frac{r_2}{r_3}} e^{i(\theta_2 - \theta_3)/2}$. Since $r_i = |z_i|$ the last equality is what we want.

Edit 2 : notice that as Did mentionned, there is no well defined notion of a square root of a complex number. So the usually solution is to define the square root of a complex numbers $z \in \mathbb C \backslash \mathbb R_-$ by the formula above.

Comment: Umm, can u please help me some more? How should I proceed to arrive at what Jan Eerland has "proved"? Are there some properties that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Sorry but there is no canonical function $\sqrt{\ }:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, so what does $\sqrt{z}$ mean in your answer?

Comment: Sheesh! I'm an idiot for not having been able to do this on my own! Thanks so much sir/ma'am! :)

Comment: Did : since it was not precised in the question I did assume the author took any determination of the square root on some subset of $\mathbb C$. You're right I should be more careful about it.

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar : you're welcome :)

Comment: @Did: I'm very sorry but truly, I have no idea what you just said. Can u write without all that code?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar I am very sorry but truly, I have no idea what you just asked about my comment. Can you explain yourself more clearly?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar : there is a problem for defining the square root of a complex number, since they are two possible solutions. I advice to you to read the wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers

Comment: Re Edit2, the trouble is that none of this is needed to solve **this** question.

Comment: "So the usually solution is to define the square root of a complex numbers $z \in \mathbb C \backslash \mathbb R_-$ by the formula above." Sorry but the formula above does not define a single complex number since one can choose different values of the argument $\theta$ for the same complex number $z$. See the conundrum you got yourself into? :-)

Comment: Yes, see, that's what I didn't understand. What I meant was that I didn't understand what u were trying to tell me because of all the "$\sqrt{\}...". I'm using the app so that's probably why I see the code :/ I'm gonna read the article but I understood your point. Thanks all :)

Comment: Well on $\mathbb C \backslash \mathbb R_-$ there is a well-defined notion of argument, with $\arg(z) = 0$ if $z$ is real.

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
$$
z_3^2=\frac{z_1}{z_2}
$$
(with the assumption that $z_2\ne0$) and therefore
$$
|z_3|^2=|z_3^2|=\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|=\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}
$$
because $|uv|=|u|\,|v|$ for $u,v\in\mathbb{C}$. Since the final equalities are between nonnegative real numbers, we conclude that
$$
|z_3|=\sqrt{\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}}
$$

Comment: But how is |z|²=|z²|?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar $|u|^2=u\bar{u}$ by definition. So $|uv|^2=uv\overline{uv}=(u\bar{u})(v\bar{v})=|u|^2|v|^2$. Taking square roots, we get $|uv|=|u|\,|v|$ and, in particular, $|z^2|=|z|^2$ (with $z=u=v$).

Comment: Oh crap! My bad! I'm so sorry I made u type all that. I figured it out on my own. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{z}_3=\sqrt{\frac{\text{z}_1}{\text{z}_2}}\to\left|\text{z}_3\right|=\left|\sqrt{\frac{\text{z}_1}{\text{z}_2}}\right|=\left|\left(\frac{\text{z}_1}{\text{z}_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right|=\left(\left|\frac{\text{z}_1}{\text{z}_2}\right|\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(\frac{|\text{z}_1|}{|\text{z}_2|}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{|\text{z}_1|}{|\text{z}_2|}}$$

Comment: How did u write the last step?! Is there some property that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Something to the power of 1/2 means the quare root of that something. This are basic properties of finding a complex number's modulus. You can prove those with the complex exponentials

Comment: Oh, so can you help me to prove it? Am I correct in assuming that this is the case for all exponents? That regardless of the way multiple complex numbers are connected within an expression, we simply take the mod of all of them?

Comment: You can use those for all complex numbers that are in these form! Of you look to the post of N.H. he proved some of those rules

Comment: Sorry but there is no canonical function $\sqrt{\ }:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, so what does $\sqrt{z}$ mean in your answer? Anyway, your first comment in the present thread is squarely misleading.